# Java for Multiple Synchronous Blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have some old code with many concurrency issues. The code connects to a server with a socket.
There is multiple conditionals applied on whether the socket is connected or not, this was implemented by using a Boolean variable (willy nilly used between multiple threads)

An obvious solution would be to:
Add more locks, and nest the locks such that the connection state locks both the read and write states, allowing read and write locks to be able to be made independently. This causes somewhat ugly code

**What other options are there?**

Keep in mind the system is already tested/in production and is a pretty old system with features slap-added to the existing classes (I cringe looking at the classes sometimes) rewriting the entire codebase is an option, just the last one I want to make.

EDIT:
Since I found some answers and tried to reword my question for better understanding of the situation I realized that this is not a question with a solution without asking for a rewrite of the existing code which is what I wanted to prevent, but inevitable.

Comment: Instead of doing explicit synchronization why don|t you do an intermediate queue holding the operations you want to perform and execute it in a single thread or something like that ?

Comment: I agree: *locking* is always prone to error. If possible, invest your time/energy into building something that works without such low level concepts.

Comment: @GhostCat exactly. I have the feeling the direction in which he is going is too error prone.

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Post your code and what the problem is, - there may be a much better way to do things. Also look into `ReentrantReadWriteLock`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, Read up on that, seems to be the case, I was worried about it before asking the question, I will reformulate the question.

The problem is that it is existing code with existing locking/concurrency issues, this was a attempt to fix the existing system with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect of your comment of modifying the code and the subsequent system/ regression testing. No matter if you implement something new or if you just add the synchronized blocks and locks eventualy you will have to do the same amount of testing.

Doing explicit synchronization is a risky business. It is low level and as such it is error prone.

The alternative is to redesign a  bit your system with the thought of SOLID. Create an abstraction and isolate the fragments of code that need to be synchronized in apropriate structures. I gave previously example by writing all the operations in an intermediate queue and consuming the elements in a single thread. I am not aware of your code and situation I am not aware if this is applicable. But this is an example on how you can implicitly solve your concurency issues by introducing an intermediate structure.

I think based on your comments that the key point is that no matter what you do - place sycnhronization blocks or redesign it. The amount of testing you need to perform in my opinion is the same. But having a better model would certainly save you a lot of time debugging and maintaining the code.

Comment: So rewrite all the read/write functions to be inside a  new class that will handle the locking implicitly?

Comment: @EatonEmmerich It can be one it can be more classes. You need to ensure that whatever you have it is doing single function (SOLID) But yeah delegate your concurency managment to a third party.